# How can I properly create a rendertarget using ID3D11Device5

Tags: uwp, directx, direct3d, c++-cx

What is the proper way to create a render target view using ID3D11Device5? I've got some code that works with ID3D11Device4, but upgrading it fails with an access violation when calling `CreateRenderTargetView`. This crash seems to happen in a graphics driver on both Intel Graphics and AMD Graphics PCs.

A quick way I've been able to reproduce the issue is to:

1. Create a new "DirectX 11 and XAML App (Universal Windows)" in Visual Studio 2017
2. In `pch.h`, change the `d3d11_3.h` include to `d3d11_4.h`
3. In `DeviceResources.h` change the type of `m_d3dDevice` from `Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<ID3D11Device3>` to `Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<ID3D11Device5>`.
4. Run the debug build so that debug layers are used via the `D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG` flag. The crash does not seem to occur in release builds.

Is there something this set of changes that's fundamentally incorrect or is this a bug?

Edit: The same behavior seems to happen in an equivalent desktop Windows application as well on a hardware device. On the reference device, `E_INVALIDARG` is returned from `CreateRenderTarget1`

Comment: I would test the code in a console app first to check if the access denied error is related to the UWP sandbox or not.

Comment: @MehrzadChehraz Thanks for the suggestion. I just tried and it also happens in a standard desktop application.

Comment: I got this same error developing a standard desktop app from scratch. CreateRenderTargetView1 crashes on debug when using ID3D11Device5, but it doesn't with ID3D11Device4, and it also doesn't crashes on release.